# How to reimplement setData for a QListWidgetItem in PyQt/PySide?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

When I subclass `QListWidgetItem`, my reimplementation of `setData`, in which I reset the item's text attribute,  the edit does not go through, but the text simply reverts back to what was there before the editor was opened:

```
class ListItem(QtGui.QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, text, listWidget):
        QtGui.QListWidgetItem.__init__(self, text)
        self.listWidget = listWidget
        self.string = text

    def setData(self, role, value):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            print "new value, previous value: ", value, self.string
            self.string = value
            return True
        return False
```

Even using this simple subclass, when I hit `return` after editing an item, it reverts. If this was `QAbstract*Model`, I would emit a `dataChanged` signal to tell the model/view that the data have changed, but I do not think this works in QListWigets.

I have even tried adding `self.setText(value)`, but the behavior is the same.

I could just end by going back to the base class: `QtGui.QListWidgetItem.setData()` once I have set the other item attributes myself. But my goal is to exert a bit more control over the text myself, not just punt to the base class.

Comment: You must always pass `self` as the first parameter when calling base-class methods (unless you're using `super`).

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks I have changed the question a lot because your answer showed the original was a silly mistake.

Comment: If you want more control, you will need to override `data()` as well as `setData`, and handle each role as appropriate. For roles you don't want to handle, call the base-class method instead. Also note that the return type of `setData` is `void`, so  there's no point returning anything from it.